# Label a triangle

Tags: pstricks, technical-drawing

How would I produce a triangle (with each side a different length) with labeled edges and angles? I'be managed to produce a triangle using `pstricks`, the code it

```
\begin{pspicture}(0,-1.34)(6.8,1.34)
\psline[linewidth=0.04](6.78,0.88)(0.0,1.32)(0.58,-1.32)(6.74,0.86)(6.74,0.86)(6.76,0.84)
\end{pspicture}
```

and the output is

[image]

How would I label the lines and the angles?

I've looked around at answers to similar questions and they all use tiks. I'm happy to start learning that if it makes the  drawing easier.

Comment: `pst-eucl` is probably what you are looking for: see in particular the page 8 and 9 of its documentation: http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-eucl/doc/pst-eucl-doc.pdf

Comment: I would recommend using the [tag:tikz-pgf] package instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `tkz-euclide` package. Look at the following example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,positioning,quotes,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (135:3) coordinate (A) (45:4) coordinate (B) (0:0) coordinate (C);
\draw (A)
-- (B) node [at start, left]{$A$} node [midway,above, sloped]{$m+n$}
-- (C) node [at start, right]{$B$} node [midway,below, sloped] {$2\sqrt{m n}$}
-- (A) node [at start, below]{$C$} node [midway, below, sloped] {$m-n$} -- cycle;
\draw 
pic[draw, angle radius=7.5mm,"$\theta$",angle eccentricity=.7] {angle = C--A--B}
pic[draw, angle radius=7.5mm,"$\phi$",angle eccentricity=.7] {angle = A--B--C}
pic[draw, angle radius=7.5mm,"$\beta$",angle eccentricity=.6] {angle = B--C--A};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which gives this triangle:

[image]

If you were to use `PSTricks`, you can do the same example like this:

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(10,7)
    \pstGeonode[CurveType=polygon,PosAngle={180,-90,0}](1,4){A}(5,1){C}([offset=-7]{A}C){B}
    \pstMarkAngle[MarkAngleRadius=1,LabelSep=.7]{C}{A}{B}{$\theta$}
    \pstMarkAngle[MarkAngleRadius=1,LabelSep=.7]{A}{B}{C}{$\phi$}
    \pstMarkAngle[MarkAngleRadius=1,LabelSep=.6]{B}{C}{A}{$\beta$}
    \psset{shortput=nab,linestyle=none,nrot=:U}
    \pcline(A)(B)^{$m+n$}
    \pcline(A)(C)_{$m-n$}
    \pcline(C)(B)_{$2\sqrt{mn}$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Run in the sequence: LaTeX-DVI-PS-PDF to get the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here is a MetaPost version of AboAmmar's figure (same labels bar one, slightly different triangle).

Since MetaPost is now part of LuaTeX, I've included my code in a LuaLaTeX program, but it could have been created and executed independently.

NB: the following code needs the latest version of the `luamplib` package (2.10.1), which fixed a bug related to the occasional suffix (`@#`) of a `vardef` macro.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
  \mplibsetformat{metafun}
  \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
  \begin{mplibcode}
    u := 1cm;
    pair A, B, C; A = origin; B = u*(5, 2); C = u*(2, -3); 

    vardef rotatedlabel@#(expr str, pos, angl) =
      draw thelabel@#(str, pos) rotatedaround (pos, angl)
    enddef;

    beginfig(1);
      draw A--B--C--cycle;
      label.lft("$A$", A); label.rt("$B$", B); label.bot("$C$", C);
      rotatedlabel.top("$m+n$", .5[A,B], angle(B-A)); 
      rotatedlabel.bot("$2\sqrt{mn}$", .5[B,C], angle(B-C)); 
      rotatedlabel.bot("$m-n$", .5[A,C], angle(C-A));
      draw anglebetween(B--A, B--C, "$\beta$");
      anglelength := 13pt; % default 20pt
      draw anglebetween(A--B, A--C, "$\alpha$");
      draw anglebetween(C--A, C--B, "$\gamma$");
    endfig;
  \end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]